# using Notepad++ how can i make a macro type situation in which a number increments?

Tags: macros, notepad++, auto-increment, increment

for example i have about 500 lines. in the beginning of each line i want to add a number. so in line 1 i would want "1)" and then line 2 i would want "2)"

i know i can do a macro in n++, but it wouldn't be incremental. is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ incrementally replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602816/notepad-incrementally-replace)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notepad++ Macros only playback keyboard actions.  They can't do anything dynamic.

However there is a built-in(?) plugin that can do this for you.

Highlight all the code, then choose "TextFX / TextFX Tools / Insert Line Numbers"

One thing to be aware of is that it is the absolute line number within the file.  You can't start numbering on line 10 and make it say line 03 or something like that.

Answer (score 44):

Edit -> Column Editor and use the bottom option on that dialogue (Number to Insert). This way you can also start from whatever number you like and not have to have the leading zeros.

Comment: This led me to learn that you can even ALT+drag-select to enter Column Mode, which constrains your selection to a specific column(s). How cool is that?

Answer (score 7):

In the more general cases where you want to add a sequence number more selectively (e.g. in the middle of a line, or only for some lines), there are two methods:

1. Hold down alt and use your mouse to drag a rectangular region, as described in http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Column_Editing
   Then use Edit -> Column Editor -> Number to Insert as per Tom's answer.
2. Select a rectangular region again as above, copy the single character # to your clipboard, then use TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Insert (Clipboard) through lines, as described here:
   http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Clipboard_Uses#Insert_through_lines_variable_text

Answer (score 4):

You could use TextPad if you need a versatile solution to this problem. Just open the replace dialog in it; set replace mode to regex and then in replace by textbox use \i where you want an incrementing sequence to be used.

Answer (score 2):

TextFX->TextFX Tools->Insert Line Numbers

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion but isn't fully automated..
You can open a new file
Press the macro recording button:

1. insert ayting in the first line and press enter
2. Stop macro recording
3. Press "Do it many times" (I don't know how is eng. translation) and specify to repeat it for 499 times.

As answered in question https://superuser.com/questions/331098/flip-or-reverse-line-order-in-notepad do:

4. Edit > Select All
5. TextFX > TextFX Tools > Insert Line Numbers
6. If TextFX > TextFX Tools > +Sort ascending is checked, uncheck it
7. TextFX > TextFX Tools > Sort lines case sensitive (at column)
8. TextFX > TextFX Tools > Delete Line Numbers or First Word

I hope it helps, I didn't try it but I can't see how it couldn't work.. :-)