# How to copy a single line to multiple lines in Notepad++ through Macro?

Tags: macros, notepad++

I need to copy a single line to multiple lines with numbers added to the lines as shown below:

```
<item>radar1</item>
<item>radar2</item>
<item>radar3</item>
```

Is it possible to record and run Multiple times which the number also comes along with the lines chronologically through macro?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ Macros only playback keyboard actions. They can't do anything dynamic.

However there is a built-in(?) plugin that can do this for you.

Highlight all the code, then choose "TextFX / TextFX Tools / Insert Line Numbers"

One thing to be aware of is that it is the absolute line number within the file. You can't start numbering on line 10 and make it say line 03 or something like that.

Author: [using Notepad++ how can i make a macro type situation in which a number increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150097/using-notepad-how-can-i-make-a-macro-type-situation-in-which-a-number-incremen)

Comment: this is only for numbering the line which the number wont come inside the codes. I do not want line numbers. because i got some more codes on top     of above give.