# Auto increment on paste

Tags: notepad++

How could I auto-increment the number on a line-paste?

example:

```
, act.sem01 as acts01, ant.sem01 as ants01, act.sem01-ant.sem01 as difs01 ;
, act.sem02 as acts02, ant.sem02 as ants02, act.sem02-ant.sem02 as difs02 ;
, act.semNN as actsNN, ant.semNN as antsNN, act.semNN-ant.semNN as difsNN ;
```

I would like to copy-paste the 1st row for example 99 times with auto-incrementing of the 1 to 2, 3, 4... N

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to copy your line 99x and then insert line numbers like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150097/using-notepad-how-can-i-make-a-macro-type-situation-in-which-a-number-incremen) and then record a macro that uses the line numbers to overwrite the '01' of each line.